# Blender object disappers when in the play mode

Tags: python, scripting, camera

everyone! I have a problem of viewing an object in the play mode. I don't know what I could do about it.

I added 20x20 vertices of a mesh by the code in the end.

The mesh looks like this in the camera view. (a 2D Gaussian distribution)
[image]

But in the play mode, I can only see the tip of it.
[image]

I tried the camera setting: clip end to an incredibly large number like 200000, there is no change at all. Moreover, the material is set to be "opaque", so it can be detected by the camera.

What could I do?

I tried the python template addon_add_object.py, the added plane cannot be seen in the play mode, either. My code is on the basis of that template, so is there any change I could make on the code?

Thank you in advance!

```
import bpy
import numpy as np
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy_extras.object_utils import AddObjectHelper, object_data_add
from mathutils import Vector


def add_object(self, context):

    #ob = context.object
    #sigma = ob.mean_value
    #mean = ob.std_deviation
    #rou = ob.covar
    
    sigma = 0.5 
    mean = 0
    rou = 0
    
    verts = []
    edges = []
    index = 20
    for x in np.linspace(-4,4,index):
        for y in np.linspace(-4,4,index):
            z_val = 1/(2*np.pi*sigma*sigma*np.sqrt(1-rou**2))*\
                np.exp(-(1/(2*(1-rou**2)))*(((x-mean)**2/sigma**2)-\
                2*rou*(x-mean)*(y-mean)/(sigma*sigma) +\
                (y-mean)**2/sigma**2))
            verts.append(Vector((x, y , z_val)))
    for j in range(index*index):
        edge = [j, j+1]
        edges.append(edge)

    faces = []
    #faces = [[0, 1, 2, 3],[4,5,6,7],[0,1,5,4]]
    for i in range(index-1):
        for m in range(index-1):
            faces.append([m*index+i,m*index+i+1,\
            m*index+index+1+i,m*index+index+i])
    

    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(name="Gaussian Distribution")
    mesh.from_pydata(verts, edges, faces)
    # useful for development when the mesh may be invalid.
    # mesh.validate(verbose=True)
    object_data_add(context, mesh, operator=self)


class OBJECT_OT_add_object(Operator, AddObjectHelper):
    """Create a new Mesh Object"""
    bl_idname = "mesh.add_object"
    bl_label = "Add Mesh Object"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}


    def execute(self, context):

        add_object(self, context)

        return {'FINISHED'}


# Registration

def add_object_button(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(
        OBJECT_OT_add_object.bl_idname,
        text="Add Object",
        icon='PLUGIN')


# This allows you to right click on a button and link to the manual
def add_object_manual_map():
    url_manual_prefix = "https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/"
    url_manual_mapping = (
        ("bpy.ops.mesh.add_object", "editors/3dview/object"),
        )
    return url_manual_prefix, url_manual_mapping


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_add_object)
    bpy.utils.register_manual_map(add_object_manual_map)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_mesh_add.append(add_object_button)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_add_object)
    bpy.utils.unregister_manual_map(add_object_manual_map)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_mesh_add.remove(add_object_button)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Your script didn't run for me, it threw an error on bpy.types.INFO_MT_mesh_add.remove(add_object_button). That said, did you try changing the near clipping as well as the far clipping?

Comment: It is in Blender 2.79. Could you try -- Template -Python -addon_add_object.py instead? Does it work? I cannot see the mesh it creates in the play mode, either. I tried the near clipping, too.

Comment: I see. The normal vec of the surface is up-side-down, so I couldn't see the surface from above the surface.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion! Problem solved.